# Azure VPN connectivity using OpenVPN

Tags: azure, vpn

I cannot connect to AZ OpenVPN at all. I've downloaded config files from AZ Portal and added my cert and keys. Now I receive following in client log:

```
⏎[Aug 10, 2022, 20:48:14] Connecting to [azuregateway-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.vpn.azure.com]:443 (20.XXX.XX.XXX) via TCPv4
⏎[Aug 10, 2022, 20:48:14] EVENT: CONNECTING ⏎[Aug 10, 2022, 20:48:14] Tunnel Options:V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1523,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,keydir 1,cipher AES-256-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 256,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client
⏎[Aug 10, 2022, 20:48:14] Creds: UsernameEmpty/PasswordEmpty
⏎[Aug 10, 2022, 20:48:14] Peer Info:
IV_VER=3.git::d3f8b18b
IV_PLAT=win
IV_NCP=2
IV_TCPNL=1
IV_PROTO=30
IV_CIPHERS=AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:CHACHA20-POLY1305
IV_AUTO_SESS=1
IV_GUI_VER=OCWindows_3.3.6-2752
IV_SSO=webauth,openurl,crtext

⏎[Aug 10, 2022, 20:48:14] Transport Error: OpenSSLContext::SSL::read_cleartext: BIO_read failed, cap=2576 status=-1: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
⏎[Aug 10, 2022, 20:48:14] EVENT: CERT_VERIFY_FAIL OpenSSLContext::SSL::read_cleartext: BIO_read failed, cap=2576 status=-1: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed⏎[Aug 10, 2022, 20:48:14] EVENT: DISCONNECTED ⏎
```

Any help on that?

Answer (score 0):

*As per the Error screenshot I can see that there some issue with your SSL certificate and because of that you are unable to connect.*

*Check this SSH configurations once again and retry the connection.*

- *Try to configure your VM over SSH using admin account*
- *and when prompt with agreement select yes*
- *make the server node as primary access*
- *Use the port value as 943 for Admin WEB UI*
- *TCP port value should be 443*
- *Now it will prompt for VPN access select that*

[image]

*For complete information go through this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73345493/azure-vpn-connectivity-using-openvpn).*